# I enter `wsl` Windows answers `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows

> Edition    Windows 11 Pro
> Version    22H2
> OS build   22621.1992
> Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22644.1000.0

There is a enabled check "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in Windows features.
I can see `wsl.exe` in `c:\windows\system32`. But if I write

```
c:\windows\system32\wsl.exe <any command or nothing>
```

I get

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I type the command in Windows PowerShell Terminal and in old cmd.exe and get the same result.
I have already tried to check off "Windows Subsystem for Linux", restart and check it on, but it hasn't helped.
[image]

**UPDATE**
I always ran `wsl` from PS. But now I've run `wsl` from Windows+R command prompt. And dialog box was shown:

```
[Window Title]
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_1.0.3.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wsl.exe

[Content]
Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_1.0.3.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wsl.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

[OK]
```

WTH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to open `Microsoft Store` and update everything. I had quite a few outdated applications including `Windows Substystem for Linux`. After I updated them all I got an access to `wsl` tool.